# text field,scrollView problem in Xib

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am creating a registration form which include a great deal of data on a page, so I am using scroll view, textfield, labels, pickers and buttons.

Now it is too complicated to handle in Xib. I am creating the whole thing through IBOutlet.

I am also using 9 subviews.

Can any one offer any suggestions on how to reduce the work or simplify the problem? This is really taking a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hiren bhadreshwara:

You can dynamically create the controls like  scroll view, textfield, labels, pickers buttons instead of adding them into XIB.

This would decrease the amount of complexity which is currently present in your XIB.

If you still have some problem then you can just leave me a comment.

Hope this helps you. :-)

Comment: thnx man. i am working with https:// secure data but i never work with this type of data. normally m try to receive the data but in response i get the error from json side.. and i think normal methods i can not used for this type of data. what i should do?

Comment: didReceivwResponse
 didReceiveData
 -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x4e0cc50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"
)

Comment: May be it has something to do with how you format your Jsonstring on your server side

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the amount of data you are capturing? Do you really need it all?

Or, split it up into several pages with just a few fields on each page.